# Create VCL for Magento 2

Tags: admin, cache, magento2, performance, varnish

In the official documentation it says Varnish is supported out of the box and there should be an option to generate a VCL file compatible with Varnish 3 and Varnish 4. I can't find this using the admin panel or CLI. Has anyone tried to use this feature?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image: screenshot]

> 1. Log in to the Magento Admin as an administrator.
> 2. Click **STORES** > **Configuration** > ADVANCED > **System** > **Full Page Cache**
> 3. From the **Caching Application** list, click **Varnish Caching**
> 4. Enter a value in the **TTL for public content** field.
> 5. Expand **Varnish Configuration** and enter the following information:
> 6. Click **Save Config**.
> 7. Click one of the export buttons to create a `default.vcl` you can use with Varnish.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-magento.html